# Swift constraint makes wrong element width smaller

Tags: swift, label, width, constraints, uistackview

so i have this `UIStackView` on the left of my view, I've done this using trailing space, and i have label, i want it to be on the left of my stack view, when i set constraints for label, instead of tightening label it makes stack view smaller, how do i solve this problem? i couldn't find any answers anywhere, i don't want to set the width constraint to the stack view because it might change, i just want to prioritize stack views width over label width

constraints:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.mainView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: stackView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10)
NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.mainView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: stackView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10)

NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: Label, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10)
NSLayoutConstraint(item: Label, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)
NSLayoutConstraint(item: Stack, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: Label, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it by making distribution of stack view .FillEqually